# Can't click on element from jQuery html()

Tags: jquery, click

I have this jQuery AJAX code, when the request is successful, it does this:

```
success: function(msg)
{
    $('.login-msg').css('color', 'green');
    $('.login-msg').hide().html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
    $('#user-tools').hide().html('<span class="user-credits"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logout-btn">Logout</a></span>').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

However, I can't click on the link with the class `logout-btn` which has a jQuery click function which will logout the user, although when I refresh the page, it still has the HTML as this:

```
<span class="user-credits"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logout-btn">Logout</a></span>
```

But how come I can't click on it to do the click function done here:

```
$('.logout-btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'include/logout.php',
    cache: false,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $('.logout-btn').html('<p><img src="img/loading.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom;" /> Refreshing...</p>');

            setTimeout(function() 
            { 
               window.location.reload(); 
            }, 1000);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $('.logout-btn').css('color', 'red');
            $('.logout-btn').hide().html('Error trying to log out, try again later').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this so it works on future elements as well:

```
$('.logout-btn').live('click', function(){
```

This relies on event bubbling, so it works if the element is present when it's bound or not...so your dynamically added links will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use livequery. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: The `live` function is built into jQuery and does has the same functionality.

Comment: @nickf - It's worth noting it's not the same, it'll accomplish the same task in *this* case, but `.livequery()` still has many uses `.live()` doesn't cover  :)

Answer (score 0):

`click` will only register the event handler to those elements that are registered in the DOM at the time the event handler is bound.

Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead:

```
$('.logout-btn').live('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'include/logout.php',
    cache: false,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $('.logout-btn').html('<p><img src="img/loading.gif" style="vertical-align: bottom;" /> Refreshing...</p>');

            setTimeout(function() 
            { 
               window.location.reload(); 
            }, 1000);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $('.logout-btn').css('color', 'red');
            $('.logout-btn').hide().html('Error trying to log out, try again later').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.click()`, use `.live()`

```
$('.logout-btn').live('click', function() {
     // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the click event handler defined? If it's attached when the DOM has loaded, it's not going to work for a `<span>` inserted into the DOM at a later point. You either need to attach the event handler after adding the element to the DOM or use some form of event delegation, most likely through using [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.live()` I'd strongly recommend the use of `.delegate()`. Usage:

Assuming the following markup:

```
<div id="parent-box">
    <span class="user-credits">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logout-btn">Logout</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

You'd code something like:

```
$("#parent-box").delegate(".logout-btn", "click", function(event) {
    // Do something
});
```

In plain English, you're delegating to `#parent-box` a function that will trigger every time you click `.logout-btn`.

PD: Remember to chain properties in jQuery:

```
$('.logout-btn').css('color', 'red').hide().html('Error trying to log out, try again later').fadeIn('slow');
```